# Linear systems. Please help me solve this

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Please help me solve this.

> Consider for every real number $a$ the linear system of equations:
>   $$
> \begin{align} 
>  x +( a + 1 )y + a^2 z &= a^3 \\
>  (1-a)x +( 1 - 2a )y   &= a^3 \\
>  x +( a + 1 )y + az    &= a^2 \\
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> 1. Find the solution for $a = 2$;
> 2. Find the values of a for which the system has no solution, infinitely many solutions, and a unique solution;
> 3. Find the solution for $a = -1$.

Comment: You should include some details on where you're getting stuck, otherwise we have no idea what kind of answer to give. For example, are you able to do questions (a) and (c)?

Comment: sorry for that ,
honestly iam getting stuck on part b so can u help me please !

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a+1 & a^{2} \\
1-a & 1-2a & 0 \\
1 & a+1 & a%
\end{array}%
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z%
\end{array}%
\right) =\mathbf{A\cdot }\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z%
\end{array}%
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a^{3} \\
a^{3} \\
a^{2}%
\end{array}%
\right) .
$$
In general, if $\det \mathbf{A}\neq 0$, $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible and you
have a unique solution.
If you subtract the third equation from the first you obtain
$$
\mathbf{B}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z%
\end{array}%
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & a(a-1) \\
1-a & 1-2a & 0 \\
1 & a+1 & a%
\end{array}%
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z%
\end{array}%
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a^{2}(a-1) \\
a^{3} \\
a^{2}%
\end{array}%
\right)
$$
Here
$$
\det \mathbf{B}=a(a-1)\{(1-a)(1+a)-1+2a\}=a^{2}(a-1)(2-a),
$$
which vanishes for $a=0,1,2$. For $a=1$, $z$ is undetermined and you can
have an infinite number of solutions. In this case you find $x$ and $y$ by
substituting $a=1$. If $a=0$ then we have $x=y=0$ and $z$ is undetermined.
The case $a=2$ you already considered.